# Religious tolerance

Tags: shirk, kaabah, freedom-of-belief

When Muhammad (saw) conquered Makkah why didn't he just remove the idols instead of destroying them? I understand that the Kaabah is a place of worship for Muslims but removal would have been a valid option too. Doesn't that conflict with no compulsion in religion and freedom of non-muslims?

P.S I'm a believing and practicing Muslim engaged in a debate with an ex-muslim

Comment: How does this conflict with "no compulsion in religion"? If someone wanted to keep worshiping their easily-smashed idols, what's stopping them from doing so?

Comment: Please try reading works of tafsir and understand the context and concept of the relevant verses.

Comment: Who told you that Islam gives full religious freedom to non-Muslims? If you could provide the evidence that would be helpful. And there is no compulsion in ''acceptance'' of religion in Islam. Do you think a person will be spared if he was previously a Muslim but becomes an apostate under Islamic ruling? We are Muslims, we must believe in the Quran and Sunnah blindly. Prove to that non-Muslim that Islam is the truth. Don't try to explain the wisdom behind the prohibition of a certain thing, Allah has prohibited that thing that's it.